# Odds of 3 identical digits in a row in a 6 digit number

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If I have a 6 digit random number what are the odds of me having 3 consecutive digits be identical?  examples $341117$ or $444628$

I thought of two ways to answer this and they give very different results. One (or both!) are incorrect.  Can someone explain to me what is wrong with the reasoning in the wrong one?

First approach:  There are 4 possible positions for the 3 identical digits, and at each position there are ten possibilities $(000, 111, 222....999)$. The remaining digits do not matter. So that sounds like out of the one million number combinations from 000000 all the way up to 999999 there are 40 ways this could happen, so this smells like 40 out of 1 million or one chance out of 25000. (and I think I now see a flaw in that reasoning)

Second approach (and now I realize, gives the right answer): For each of the first 4 digits it does not matter what value they have.  There is then a one in 100 chance the next two digits will be the same. so the odds of this happening are 4 times 1 in 100 or one chance in 25.

What I missed from the first approach is that for each set of three digits in a row, there are one thousand combinations for the other three digits, so for each of those 40 ways, there are actually 1000 possibilities (example 111432 and 111739 are two of the 1000 ways to have a 6 digit number starting with 111) . So 40,000 ways out of a million numbers is 1 in 25.

I guess this is not even a question anymore, but it was when I started writing, so I will share.

Comment: I believe that neither of your ways are correct. $\quad$ Hint: You double counted 111222 and 111122. $\quad$

Comment: One correct approach is going to involve an absolute mess of casework. I'm not sure there's an elegant solution

Comment: You are also counting numbers with leading zeros.  I don't know if you meant to, but we would usually call the group of them digit strings instead of numbers.  Does $000123$ count?

Comment: I tried splitting it up into a really large number of cases. I wish I was able to find a more elegant solution. The probability I got was $3691/100000$, but it's very likely that I overlooked some case.

Comment: Do you want **exactly** three consecutive digits the same, or **at least** three consecutive digits the same ?

Answer (score 4):

Neither $1$ in $25$  nor $1$ in $25000$ is the correct probability.

---

To clarify: we are including leading zeroes in the six-digit sequence, so "$001234$" would be one possibility, even though that would typically be called a four-digit number.

---

**Case 1:** Sequences of the form AAAAAA, of which there are exactly $10$, one for each digit.

**Case 2:** Sequences of the form AAABBB, with A and B distinct. There are $10$ ways to choose the digit A, and for each of these, $9$ ways to choose the digit B. There are therefore $90$ such sequences.

**Case 3:** Sequences of the form XAAAYZ and XYAAAZ. Here, the XYZ need not be distinct digits, but they are not the same digit as A. There are $10$ ways to choose the digit A, and $9^3$ ways to choose the three other digits. There are therefore $7290$ sequences of the form XAAAYZ and $7290$ sequences of the form XYAAAZ, for a total of $14580$ sequences in this case.

**Case 4:** Sequences of the form AAAAXY, XAAAAY, and XYAAAA. Here, the XY need not be distinct digits, but they are not the same digit as A. There are $10$ ways to choose the digit A, and $9^2$ ways to choose the two other digits. There are therefore $810$ sequences in each of the three formats, for a total of $2430$ in this case.

**Case 5:** Sequences of the form AAAAAB and BAAAAA. There are $10$ ways to choose the digit A, and, for each of these, $9$ ways to choose the digit B. There are therefore $90$ sequences in each of the two formats, for a total of $180$ in this case.

**Case 6:** Sequences of the form AAAXYZ, with XYZ not all the same, and X not the same as A. There are $10$ ways to choose A, and given this, $9$ ways to choose X. YZ can be any of the $10^2$ possible two digit sequences, other than XX, so there are $10^2-1=99$ possibilities for YZ. This gives a total of $10\cdot 9 \cdot 99 = 8910$ sequences in this case.

**Case 7:** Sequences of the form XYZAAA, with XYZ not all the same, and Z not the same as A. The reasoning is the exact same as in Case 6, so we have $8910$ sequences.

**Case 8:** Sequences of the form AAAABA and ABAAAA. There are $10\cdot 9 = 90$ of each, for a total of $180$ sequences in this case.

**Case 9:** Sequences of the form XAAAYA and AXAAAY. Here, X and Y need not be distinct, but must be different from A. There are $10$ ways to choose A, and $9^2$ ways to choose X and Y. This gives $810$ sequences for each of the two formats, for a total of $1620$ sequences in this case.

---

Summing these nine cases gives a total of

$$10 + 90 + 14580 + 2430 + 180 + 8910  + 8910 + 180 + 1620 = 36910$$ sequences in which there's a digit repeat of length $\geq 3$.

---

Finally, the total number of six-digit sequences is $10^6$, so the probability of getting a digit repeat of length $\geq 3$ is $$\displaystyle\frac{36910}{1000000} \, = \, \boxed{3.691\%\,}$$

This is about $1$ in $27$.

Comment: (+1) The result without leading zeroes is the same: For any *fixed* first digit the percentage is the same, so it is also the same for a first digit $\neq 0$.

Comment: This is a carefully written correct answer, but I think using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle is easier given the symmetries in the problem.

Comment: I am counting leading zeros because I started thinking about this when my 6 digit RSA SecurID that rotates to a new number every 60 seconds displayed three consecutive digits.

I think you are wrong in your count. Lets take X111XX. There are 1000 ways to express that number and that 1000 ways includes 311147 and it also includes 111111.  I don't care what the Xs are, they can be any digit including 1. There are 1000 possible combinations for those three Xs.

On the other hand, someone else came up with the same answer, so perhaps we are answering different questions.

Comment: The issue is that there is some overlap between X111XX and XX111X. For example, 211113 counts in both of those, but should only be counted once. This is just one example of thousands of possible overlaps. The way in which I have broken down the cases ensures that there is no such overlap.

Comment: As for the correctness of the answer, I am almost certain now that it is correct, seeing that we now have 4 different answers from different people (all using different and interesting methods) to arrive at the same result: that $36910$ sequences of the $1000000$ possible sequences have a string of at least three digits in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Well , I think that solving these type of questions by using classical methods is cumbersome process. We can confuse or make overcounting.

Hence , I will suggest you very powerful tool , it is RECURRENCE RELATION .

However, using classical recurrence relation is cumbersome process ,as well. We need some assistant to make easy our recurrence relation , it is called  GOULDEN -JACKSON -CLUSTER METHOD http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036

I assume that , you will read the article and learn what it is . It can take long time to teach it here , best way reading the paper . Hence  , i am jumping into the question .

According to the paper , our alphabet consist of $10$ elements such as $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ . Moreover , our bad words are $\{000,111,222,333,444,666,777,888,999\}$.

Now , we will find such string which do not contain the bad words . However, we want that such bad words must be included , so when we find such string which do not contain any of the bad words , we we subtract it from the total ,i.e , $10^6$ ,i.e by showing it with generating functions $\frac{1}{1-10x}$

Now  , it is the for finding our strings that does not contain any of bad words such that $\{000,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999\}$.

We know that $$F(x)= \frac{1}{1-dx-weight(C)}$$ where $d=10$ and $weight(C)=weight(C[aaa])$ where $"aaa"$ represent the elements in the set of bad words.

Now , lets find $weight(C[aaa])$ 's ,according to the paper. Because of all bad words have the same lenght , when we find it for one element , we can multiply it by $10$.

According to the paper , $$weight(C[000])+weight(C[111])+weight(C[222])+weight(C[333])+weight(C[444])+weight(C[555])+weight(C[666])+weight(C[777])+weight(C[888])+weight(C[999])= \frac{-x^3}{1+x+x^2}$$

So , when multipy it by $10$ , we obtain $$\frac{-10x^3}{1+x+x^2}$$

Hence , our generating function is $$\frac{1+x+x^2}{1-9x-9x^2}$$ ,when we put all variable in their place in the formula $$F(x)= \frac{1}{1-dx-weight(C)}$$ where $d=10$ and $weight(C)= \frac{-10x^3}{1+x+x^2}$.

We know that result of this generating function gives us the strings that do not contain any three consecutive numbers such as $000,111,...,999$.

However , we want the strings that contain these three consecutive strins , so  we must subtract our foregoing generating function from total ,i.e , $\frac{1}{1-10x}$.

Then , $$\frac{1}{1-10x} - \frac{1+x+x^2}{1-9x-9x^2} = \frac{10x^3}{1-19x+81x^2+90x^3} = 10x^3 +190x^4 +2800x^5 +\color{blue}{36910x^6} +
457390x^7+...$$

You can see it : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%2810x%5E3%29%2F%281-19x%2B81x%5E2%2B90x%5E3%29

If we want to rite it like ,we obtain $$a_n=19a_{n-1}-81a_{n-2}-90a_{n-3}$$

I know ,this process seem horrible , but it is the best way to calculate without doubt.Moreover , this process gives you all $n$ -digits that satisfy your condition for example , if $n=5$ , then it is $2800$ , if $n=7$ , then it is $457390$

Answer (score 1):

**Interpretation:**  We will find the number of six-digit decimal strings (meaning the leading digit may be zero) in which there are at least three consecutive identical digits.

The problem can be solved with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Since there are six digits in the string, a string of three consecutive identical digits must begin in one of the first four positions.  Define $A_k$, $1 \leq k \leq 4$, to be the set of outcomes in which there are three consecutive identical digits beginning in the $k$th position.  Then the number of six-digit decimal strings with at least three consecutive identical digits is
\begin{align*}
& |A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4|\\
& \quad = |A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3| + |A_4|\\
& \qquad - |A_1 \cap A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_4| - |A_2 \cap A_3| - |A_2 \cap A_4| - |A_3 \cap A_4|\\
& \quad\qquad + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| + |A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| + |A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|\\& \qquad\qquad - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|
\end{align*}

$|A_1|$:  The first three digits must be the same.  There are $10$ ways to select the repeated digit and $10$ choices for each of the remaining three digits, so $|A_1| = 10^4$.

By symmetry,
$$|A_1| = |A_2| = |A_3| = |A_4| = 10^4$$

$|A_1 \cap A_2|$:  This means the first, second, and third digits are the same, as are the second, third, and fourth digits.  Since these sets of identical digits overlap, the first four digits must be the same.  There are $10$ ways to select the repeated digit and $10$ choices for each of the remaining two digits.  Thus, $|A_1 \cap A_2| = 10^3$.

By symmetry,
$$|A_1 \cap A_2| = |A_2 \cap A_3| = |A_3 \cap A_4| = 10^3$$

$|A_1 \cap A_3|$:  This means the first, second, and third digits are the same, as are the third, fourth, and fifth digits.  Since these sets of identical digits overlap, the first five digits must be the same.  There are $10$ ways to select the repeated digit and $10$ choices for the remaining digit.  Hence, $|A_1 \cap A_3| = 10^2$.

By symmetry,
$$|A_1 \cap A_3| = |A_2 \cap A_4| = 10^2$$

$|A_1 \cap A_4|$:  This means the first, second, and third digits are the same, and the fourth, fifth, and sixth digits must be the same.  These two sets of identical digits do not overlap.  Thus, there are $10$ choices for the digit that appears in the first three positions and $10$ choices for the digit that appears in the last three positions.  Thus, $|A_1 \cap A_4| = 10^2$.

$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|$:  This means the first, second, and third digits are the same; the second, third, and fourth digits are the same; and the third, fourth, and fifth digits are the same.  Since these three sets of identical digits overlap, the first five digits must be the same.  Since there are $10$ choices for the repeated digit and $10$ choices for the remaining digit,
$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = 10^2$.

By symmetry,
$$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = |A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| = 10^2$$

$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4|$:  This means the first, second, and third digits are the same; the second, third, and fourth digits are the same; and the fourth, fifth, and sixth digits are the same.  Since these three sets of identical digits overlap, all six digits must be the same.  There are $10$ choices for the repeated digit, so $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| = 10$.

By symmetry,
$$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4| = |A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| = 10$$

$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4|$:  This means the first, second, and third digits are the same; the second, third, and fourth digits are the same; the third, fourth, and fifth digit are the same; and the fourth, fifth, and sixth digits are the same.  Since these four sets of identical digits overlap, all six digits must be the same.  There are $10$ choices for the repeated digit, so $|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4| = 10$.

Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4| = 4 \cdot 10^4 - 3 \cdot 10^3 - 3 \cdot 10^2 + 2 \cdot 10^2 + 2 \cdot 10 - 10 = 36,910$$
Since there are $10^6 = 1,000,000$ six-digit decimal strings, the probability that a randomly selected six-digit decimal string contains at least three consecutive identical digits is
$$\frac{36,910}{1,000,000} = 0.03691$$

Comment: I am happy that there are so many ways to solve the same problem. +1

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) with three states.  Take as start situation a single digit number and add another digit in each step of the Markov process.  The meaning of the three states is

1. No three consecutive digits are equal and the last digit differs from the one before it.
2. No three consecutive digits are equal but the last two digits are equal.
3. There are three consecutive equal digits.

This Markov chain has the following transition matrix:
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{9}{10} & \frac{9}{10} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{10} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{10} & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Then the question asks for the probability to reach state $3$ from state $1$ in five steps.  This probability is given by the lower left entry in $M^5$ (column one, row three).  A direct matrix computation shows that this probability equals $0.03691$.

Alternatively, a linear recursion can be used to compute the probablity $p_n$ of three consecutive equal digits in an $n$-digit number.  This probability $p_n$ equals the lower left entry of the matrix $M^{n-1}$. The characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $$\det(\lambda I - M) = \lambda^3 - \frac{19}{10}\lambda^2 + \frac{81}{100}\lambda + \frac{9}{100}$$

and by the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) this leads to the following linear recursion for $p_n$:

$$p_{n+3} = \frac{19}{10}p_{n+2} - \frac{81}{100} p_{n+1} - \frac{9}{100} p_n.$$

Now it is an easy calculation to compute the sequence $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ starting from the first three values $0,\ 0,\ 0.01$:

$$0,\ 0,\ 0.01,\ 0.019,\ 0.028,\ 0.03691,\ 0.045739, \ldots $$

Comment: Wow!! I wouldn't have thought to use Markov chains here - I love this solution